SQL Time Intervals



RegistrationDate




2024-10-31 07:30:00.000


2024-10-31 07:50:00.000


2024-10-31 08:40:00.000


2024-10-31 09:30:00.000


2024-10-31 10:40:00.000


2024-10-31 11:30:00.000


2024-10-31 13:00:00.000


2024-10-31 13:50:00.000



I have the above list of times, I want another column to indicate 'Current Period' if it falls within this..
for exam current time is 11:19 I want the I want the 10:40 rows to show current period
 SELECT 
  DISTINCT AttendanceRegister.RegistrationDate 
FROM 
  AttendanceRegister 
WHERE 
  CAST(
    AttendanceRegister.RegistrationDate AS DATE
  ) = CAST(
    GETDATE() AS DATE
  )


Looks like SQL Server, but please tag your RDBMS

Also - please take the time to format your question to make it readable to other users
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Thanks, not sure how to do this. Just signed in today - always used this for searching
Posting for the very first time

Can you help with the answer, please
@MattEvans

Tagging is a simple as editing your question and adding e.g. 'SQL Server', formatting help is in the link I included in my comment

Found it Thank you :)

You say yourself ... 'if it falls within this'.
Hence, your query is wrong.
Maybe something like:

order the data by date
select where the date > current date
get the first


The actual data is more than 11000 rows, I distinct it to show the time intervals
get first is not helping me

In SQL Server, the right way of comparing datetimes by date only is this:
...
WHERE
    AttendanceRegister.RegistrationDate >= GETDATE() AND
    AttendanceRegister.RegistrationDate < dateadd(day, 1, GETDATE())


create table dbo.Registration(
RegistrationDate datetime);


insert into dbo.Registration (registrationdate) values (dateadd(hour,-5,getdate()))
insert into dbo.Registration (registrationdate) values (dateadd(hour,-4,getdate()))
insert into dbo.Registration (registrationdate) values (dateadd(hour,-3,getdate()))
insert into dbo.Registration (registrationdate) values (dateadd(hour,-2,getdate()))
insert into dbo.Registration (registrationdate) values (dateadd(hour,1,getdate()))
insert into dbo.Registration (registrationdate) values (dateadd(hour,2,getdate()))
insert into dbo.Registration (registrationdate) values (dateadd(hour,3,getdate()))


SELECT 
    registrationdate AS registrationstart,
    LEAD(registrationdate) OVER (ORDER BY registrationdate) AS registrationend,
    CASE 
        WHEN GETDATE() >= registrationdate 
             AND GETDATE() < LEAD(registrationdate) OVER (ORDER BY registrationdate)
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END IsCurrent
FROM 
    dbo.registration;




registrationstart
registrationend
IsCurrent




2024-10-31 05:33:00.847
2024-10-31 06:33:00.847
0


2024-10-31 06:33:00.847
2024-10-31 07:33:00.850
0


2024-10-31 07:33:00.850
2024-10-31 08:33:00.850
0


2024-10-31 08:33:00.850
2024-10-31 11:33:00.850
1


2024-10-31 11:33:00.850
2024-10-31 12:33:00.853
0


2024-10-31 12:33:00.853
2024-10-31 13:33:00.853
0


2024-10-31 13:33:00.853
NULL
0




This looks interesting
and will this work for Thousands of rows as well?
Thank you, but my intervals are not constant in my dataset. :(

It doesn't matter if your intervals aren't constant, and yes will work for large tables

I agree it'll work with a big dataset. I do wonder why you want such a convoluted query. This executes retrieves the entire dataset, and adds a isCurrent to the output.
If you have 1000s of items, it will return 1000s of items. I.e. a LOT of data. Who wants that?
I would almost argue it's easier to just write a query returning the current period (which is fast, given the date constraints, if there is an index it's a log(n) operation, and then doing a left join on any data returned. Your business layer could even do that, caching the period until it has expired
